# in-app billing developer payload redeem code

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I was testing my Android application for promo redeem and I forgot to actually set it up so now I have my friend and myself with a blank developer payload when other users will have a unique identifier when they purchase it. Is there a way to add the unique identifier to an existing payload? I don't want to check for a blank payload as that will leave a security risk. This is for a 1-time purchase (non-consumable).

```
if (payload.equals(user.getUid())){
    return true; 
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how user id's are stored? Also the code snippet can be reduced to return directly the result of the equals method call, it is not necessary to use an if statement.

Comment: Each user has their own ID based on their account. Doesn't change and it's generated on account creation (using Firebase). I have it set it when a user purchases the in-app purchase and it works fine. I pass the payload into the `laucnhPurchaseFlow` method and it works perfectly, however I did not set up the redeem method prior to testing it by accident. So moving forward the payload is return, but myself and one of my friends now have a payload of "" (blank). Wanting to know if it's possible to fix his and my payload.